# Pick value from array based on the previous value

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I have array has row's sizes that i need and pick up randomly like this

```js
const Numbers = ["8", "4", "6", "2"];
const randomNumber = Numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * Numbers.length)];
console.log(randomNumber)
```

this will give me a random value from the array

Now what i want to do is pick 3 numbers sum of them is 12 and after that it reset and start again.

**Example:**

Random array picked number 8
after that the number should be 4 OR number 2 twice
then start all over again

picked number 4 so the available numbers should be
4 twice
OR
2 four times
OR
4 once and 2 twice
...etc and so on

so the sum should be 12 then reset again

of course all this will be inside loop but what i want to know is the best way to do this.

====Update====

this is the HTML used

randomRow should have value every 3 row's should be 12

```
for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

    document.getElementById("someID").innerHTML += `

                <div class="col-`+randomRow+`">
<p>Hello</p>
                </div>`

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the below little game, it uses your case, it calculates the total sum of your randomNumber from the source array.

It checks if the sum is >= 12. and rests the game!

Does this helps?

```js
const Numbers = [8, 4, 6, 2];
var randomNumber = 0;
var sum = 0;

function calcSum() {

  randomNumber = Numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * Numbers.length)];
  sum = sum + randomNumber;
  if (sum >= 12) {
    document.getElementById('calculatedTotal').innerHTML = "Your score exceeded 12, click 'start game' to play again!";
    sum = 0;
    randomNumber = 0;
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('calculatedTotal').innerHTML = sum;

  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn" onclick="calcSum()">Start game!!</button>
    <h2>Your Score: </h2>
    <h3 id="calculatedTotal"></h3>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is pretty great but here is the problem, once i apply it to the row's in bootstrap it sometimes skip it, working on fixing it, but this solution is good start.

Comment: Cool, all the best!

Comment: i updated the question with HTML example, please take a look

Answer (score 1):

Each time when you pick a random number

1. you have to filter out the numbers that won't make up 12.
2. Subtract the picked number from the sum, and repeat step 1 until sum reach 0

Edit:
Updated according to the question, assuming you are using Bootstrap

```js
document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", _ => {
  let sum = +document.getElementById("sum").value;
  let numbers = document.getElementById("numbers").value.split(',').map(x=>+x);
  let picked = [];
  
  while(sum > 0) {
    // filter available `numbers` based on the `sum`
    numbers = numbers.filter(x => x <= sum);
    
    let n = numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)];
    picked.push(n);

    // subtract `n` from `sum`
    sum -= n;
  }
  
  document.getElementById("row").innerHTML = picked.map(n => `<div class="border border-dark p-3 col-${n}">col-${n}</div>`).join("");
  
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
Sum: <input type="text" id="sum" value="12" /> 
Numbers: <input type="text" id="numbers" value="8,6,2,4" /> <br/>
<button type="button" id="start">Start</button>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" id="row">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how does that apply to single number every time instead of returning array because i'm using it inside loop already.

Comment: i updated the question with HTML example, please take a look

Comment: The answer has been updated, however the solution will return any number of cols that adds up to 12.

Comment: that is good, but the problem in here is the <div..... col></div> is all inside a loop so i will have a loop inside another loop and won't work

Comment: There is no enough context given in the question, and I believe you should have the answer to your main problem. You should try incorporate the answer into your code and try to solve the looping issue.

Comment: i'm working on the code you provided and much appreciated, thank you !